# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've been searching for a solution that works but none have so far. When I try to run a program that is known to work for others, I get this error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7534 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain gui.WFPaLM
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gui.WFPaLM
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The directory "src", which contains all of the packages, is set as the Source Folder.

Edit: http://imgur.com/O45zm4t,MPYuDCa  that is what my project structure looks like.

Edit 2: I downloaded the community edition of intellij, and it worked. It's a mystery as to why.

Comment: Is the package `gui` with the class `WFPaLM` in the build path?

Comment: The package gui is inside of src, which is set as the Source Folder. (hopefully that is the info you are looking for)

Answer (score 1):

Have you compiled the project before running? (Build > Make Project <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>). Normally IntelliJ IDEA compiles a project automatically before running, but perhaps you have disabled this.

Comment: I just compiled it to be sure, same problem upon trying to run.